# Riemann-Stieltjes Improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I'm trying to prove that 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t-z}\, \mathrm{d}w(t)=0 \Longrightarrow \hbox{$w(t)$ is constant},$$
where $w\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is of bounded variation  and $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$. Can someone give me a hint? 
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean as $cte$?

Comment: Cte means constant! Here $w$ is right-continuous.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Solution

Plugging $z = \sigma + i\xi$ and considering imaginary parts only, it follows that

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{\xi}{(\sigma - t)^{2} + \xi^{2}} \, dw(t) = 0. \tag{1} $$

Integrating both sides with respect to $\sigma$ on $[a, b]$, using Fubini's Theorem,

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi} \left\{ \arctan\left(\frac{b-t}{\xi}\right) - \arctan\left(\frac{a-t}{\xi}\right) \right\} \, dw(t) = 0. $$

Since $dw(t)$ has finite total variation and the integrand is uniformly bounded by $1$, we can take limit $\xi \to 0^{+}$ inside the integral and we have

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{sgn}(t - a) - \mathrm{sgn}(t - b)}{2}  \, dw(t) = 0. $$

In particular, if both $a$ and $b$ are points of continuity of $w$, it reduces to

$$ 0 = \int_{a}^{b} dw(t) = w(b) - w(a). $$

We know that $w$ is continuous except for countably many points, so in particular $w(t) = c$ for some constant $c$ except for countably many $t$. Then the conclusion follows by the right-continuity of $w$.

---

### 2. Motivation

As $\xi \to 0^{+}$, the [Poisson kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel#On_the_upper_half-plane) in $(1)$ converges to the Dirac delta in some sense:

$$\frac{1}{\pi} \frac{\xi}{(\sigma - t)^{2} + \xi^{2}} \xrightarrow[]{\xi \to 0^{+}} \delta(\sigma - t).$$

Thus at least intuitively, we have

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(\sigma - t) \ dw(t) = 0. $$

To get rid of the Dirac delta, we integrate both sides w.r.t. $\sigma$ on $[a, b]$ and we have

\begin{align*}
0 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \{ u(b-t) - u(a-t) \} \ dw(t) = \int_{a}^{b} dw(t) = w(b) - w(a),
\end{align*}

where $u$ is the unit-step function. These lines of heuristic argument suggest that $w$ is constant, which is indeed proved above by justifying this idea.

Comment: Thank's for the motivation!!